# Replacement search plugin that reads widgets or catalogs entire page?

Tags: search

I remember seeing a search plugin that creates a database log of your pages it use for search. Does anyone know of the plugin? And would this be a good way to make the Widget Text searchable? If not is there a plugin to add widget text to the search?

Comment: For the readers: See also the [related question on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159520/wordpress-perform-a-search-on-widget-text/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [Search Engine](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-engine/) works by indexing front-end pages.

Comment: yes you are right. I found that plugin about a week ago. Its still in beta but it works almost flawlessly. there is a prob the developer is working on when you change the permalinks it show both the change and old link in the results